# swift3 how do you use os_log to show the value of a variable in the Console app

Tags: swift, swift3

When I use `os_log("Configure %@", something)` I see in the console `Configure <private>`.

I understand this is the default behavior (at least from what is describe here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging?language=objc even if it is for ObjC.)

I tried `os_log("Configure %{public}s", something)` but it just show `Configure %{public}s"`.

Using Swift 3, how do you make the variable something appear in the console ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%{public}@` ?

Comment: Correct @MartinR if you want to answer I will gladly accept.

Comment: If that was the only issue then I am more inclined to vote to close as off-topic (simple typographical error) :)

Comment: correct lets close it